# VB.net - Programmatically change column type of data bounded Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

is there a way to change the column type of a database-bounded datagridview?

I have this code so far:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT a.class_code as 'Class Code', a.sub_code as 'Subject Title', Gr_Lvl as 'Grade Level', sub_session as 'Session', TIME_FORMAT(start_time, '%h:%i%p') as 'Start Time', TIME_FORMAT(end_time, '%h:%i%p') as 'End Time', sub_day as 'Day', class_room as 'Room', sub_units as 'Units', teacher_name as 'Teacher', sub_remarks as 'Remarks', subloading_no " & _
    "FROM tbl_subloading a INNER JOIN tbl_class b on a.class_code=b.class_code INNER JOIN tbl_subject c on a.sub_code=c.sub_code  WHERE  a.class_code='" & txtClassCode.Text & "' AND sub_semester = '" & UserDataRead1("SELECT semester_desc From tbl_semester where status= 'active'") & "' ORDER BY start_time ASC"
    FillDBGrid(query, dgvClassDist)
```

And the current output:

[image]

I just want the Subject Title column to be a combobox instead of just a textfield. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: well, try this : avoid `Subject Title` from your query, populate `DataGridView` and, after populating, create combo box `Dim cbo as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, add items `cbo.Items.Add("some value"): and again, again`... and put `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` into `DataGridView` with code `dgvClassDist.Columns.Insert(1, cbo)`...  that `1` represent position where to put combobox colum... btw. there is link similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677772/combobox-column-within-databound-datagridview

Comment: You don't change the type of a column. It is what it is. You should create a column of the desired type BEFORE binding the data to the grid.  You set the `DataPropertyName` of your grid column to tell it which table column to bind to and then you won't get a column automatically created.  Check this out:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476-NET-2-0-Adding-a-ComboBox-Column-to-a-DataGridView

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a datagrid and letting it auto-generate your columns for you then you could change the column definition in the .aspx/.ascx page within your datagrid. Instead of using an asp:BoundColumn, use an asp:TemplateColumn. For example:

```
            <asp:DataGrid ID="dgMyData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="class_code" HeaderText="Class Code" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="sub_code" HeaderText="Subject Title" />
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("sub_code")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjects" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Gr_Lvl" HeaderText="Grade Level" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="sub_session" HeaderText="Session" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="start_time" HeaderText="Start Time" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm tt}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="end_time" HeaderText="End Time" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm tt}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="sub_day" HeaderText="Day" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="class_room" HeaderText="Room" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="sub_units" HeaderText="Units" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="teacher_name" HeaderText="Teacher" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="sub_remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="subloading_no" HeaderText="???" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Then you can put you code behind to fill the dropdown list(s) at an appropriate time.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class DataGridTest
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Class Subject
    Public Property Code As String
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Private SubjectList As List(Of Subject)

Private Function GetSubjects() As List(Of Subject)
    'TODO - write some code to get the subjects - below is just an example
    Return New List(Of Subject) From {New Subject With {.Code = "HIST 100", .Name = "US History"},
                                      New Subject With {.Code = "MATH 212", .Name = "Algerbra II"},
                                      New Subject With {.Code = "SCI B200", .Name = "Adv. Biology"}}
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' CACHE THE SUBJECTS
    SubjectList = GetSubjects()
    ' Get the class data but don't bother making the names pretty - let the datagrid do that
    Dim qry = "Select a.class_code, a.sub_code, Gr_Lvl, ....."
    ' execute the query and bind the data to the datagrid
    Dim dgvClassDist As DataView
    dgMyData.DataSource = dgvClassDist
    dgMyData.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub dgMyData_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgMyData.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.EditItem Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("ddlSubjects")
        ddl.Items.Clear()
        ddl.DataSource = SubjectList
        ddl.DataValueField = "Code"
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name"
        ddl.DataBind()
        Dim currentClassCode = e.Item.DataItem("class_code").ToString
        Dim item As ListItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue(currentClassCode)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            item.Selected = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Notice a few things:

1. Don't rename your columns in the query - leave the HeaderText
   property of the datagrid to do that for you.
2. Don't bother formatting the query fields like the dates - let the datagrid do that for you too using the DataFormatString property.

I wasn't 100% sure exactly when you wanted to have these dropdown lists and how you expected the users to change them so I put them in the edit template - you'll need to have an edit button in the datagrid to have the grid switch to edit mode and write more code to handle the edits. If you always want a dropdown list then you could put the DDL in the ItemTemplate and fill it in ItemDataBound event when the ItemType is an Item or Alternating item.

Comment: it's about **winforms**, not *webforms*.